# Can a localStorage value be an object or array?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, javascript-objects

I am trying to set storage in the user's computer with `localStorage("save","{teams:5, points:20}`, etc. But I'm not sure if the value can be an object. I've checked the internet, but I can't seem to find clear answers there.

```
var data={
teams:5, points:25,team1:5,team2:10, team3:5, team4:0, team5:5};
localStorage ("save", data);
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the key and value must be a [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

What you can do is serialise your data as JSON before setting it

```
localStorage.setItem('save', JSON.stringify(data))
```

When reading the value, you can *parse* it back into an object

```
let saveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('save'))
```

Comment: ...nitpicking, but about  *"must"*, you can pass non DOMString values, but their `toString()` result will be saved.

Comment: @Kaiido I tend to think of APIs like a contract

Answer (score 2):

local storage limited to handle only string key/value pairs you can do like below using JSON.stringify and while getting value JSON.parse

```
var testObject = { {name:"test", time:"Date 2017-02-03T08:38:04.449Z"} };
```

// Put the object into storage

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

// Retrieve the object from storage

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, localstorage takes string as and saves it. If you want to save any object then convert it on string and then save it. 
while fetching it from local storage you we get string. you may easily covert it into object. 
if you directly save an object into localStorage then it will be saved in such manner **"[object Object]"** and while fetching it from localStorage, you will get **"[object Object]"** as String.

**Wrong Code:**

```
var data={teams:5, points:25,team1:5,team2:10, team3:5, team4:0, team5:5};
localStorage.setItem("save", data);
localStorage.getItem("save")
```

you will get **"[object Object]"**

**Right Code:**

```
var data={teams:5, points:25,team1:5,team2:10, team3:5, team4:0, team5:5};
localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(data));
localStorage.getItem("save")
```

While fetching value from localStorage

**Wrong Code:**

```
localStorage.getItem("save")
```

It will fetch data in form of string.

**Right Code:**

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"))
```

It will return data in form of object.

I hope the solution is well explained.

Answer (score 0):

No, It can't be but you can use stringify. For example:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(r.user));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);`

For Storing a Object, you can make use of `JSON.stringify(object)` which converts the object to a string.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

> **keyName**
> A DOMString containing the name of the key you want to
> create/update.
>
> **keyValue**
> A DOMString containing the value you want to
> give the key you are creating/updating.